# Dismiss view controller flipped from modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm presenting UIViewController B modally from UIViewController A. Then, there is a UINavigationController between B and C, and C is flipped from B. I want to dismiss both B and C and animate straight to A, without showing B and hence without calling B's viewDidLoad function. I'm calling dismissViewControllerAnimated from A, but that still shows B first and hence calls B's viewDidLoad function. Forgive me if there is already a SO answer on this; I've been snooping around for hours and just can't find an answer. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Any ***Parent ViewController*** that is presented modally can be dismissed using:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Another way to do it would be using:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Let me know if it doesn't works.

Comment: I tried the second option already and that is, like I said, first showing B and calling B's viewDidLoad function. The first option's function is deprecated.